# after resizing view size, no response for tapping UIswitch, UIstepper, UIbutton in both similator and actual device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a subview and a tableviewcontroller inside a view. Please see attached pics. My view on top was like 12 points larger so I resized it and adjusted the y position of bottom tableviewcontroller also accordingly so they both align. after this change, only UISegmentedControl (delivery/takeout) is responding to tap on both simulator and device. Rest of them are not responding at all. I do not have any UITapGestureRecognizer code in the viewcontroller.m file. Am using xcode 11.7.

I tried removing all connections and added them again. tried removing all directories under "Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.1/Applications/". Reset the simulator. Tried tapping controls with "option" key pressed. Tried pressing in several places of view on top. nothing seems to help. What could be going on. there are no layout warnings in Console output. thank you.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: they all work on ipad simulator. something messed it up for iphone. i guess i have no option but to start fresh on this view.

Comment: redid all the controls in the view and its working now! crazy storyboard.